# Binomial or Negative Binomial?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Imagine a die is tossed $n$ times; What is the probability that exactly at the $n^{th}$ toss, a 4 is thrown for the $k^{th}$ time? $(1\le k \le n)$ I took the example from Bauer.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly this requires the $n$-th toss to be a $4$, which has probability$~\frac16$. You need to multiply that probability by the probability that after $n-1$ throws there were exactly $k-1$ throws equal to$~4$. You should be able to fill in the remaining details.

Comment: You mean $\frac{1}{6} {{n-1} \choose {k-1}} (\frac{1}{6})^{k-1} (\frac{5}{6})^{n-k}$

Comment: I guess I did..